# Designated Initializers for subclasses in obj-c, super noob

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sorry if this is a noob question, but if my designated initializer for my Base Class looks like

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
   if (self = [super init]) {
      _name = [name retain];

   }
   return self;
}
```

Now if I had a child class that inherits from this class and wanted to call that initializer, do I do:

```
- (id)initWithSomethingElse:(NSString *)somethingElse name:(NSString *)name {
   if (self = [super initWithName:name]) {
        _somethingElse = [somethingElse retain];

   }
   return self;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  You can call any of the superclass' initialisers, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

correct, that is how one initializes in objc.